# Python insert loop to mariadbdb not working

Tags: python, for-loop, sql-update, mariadb

I try to insert my data, but after my command update, the loop is finished.
So then I remove my update query the loop continues,  I don't understand why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector as mariadb
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import re
import os

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='xxxx', database='xxxx');
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(buffered=True)
#retrieving information

cursor.execute("SELECT Domain,Id FROM classement where Domain like '%com';")

for Domain,Id in cursor:
          counter=0
          for character in Domain:
                if (character == "."):
                        counter = counter + 1
                        if (counter==1):
                            print(Domain)
                            pingresult = Popen(['ping','-c','3', Domain], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT).communicate()[0]
                            pingresult=str(pingresult)
                            ping = pingresult.find('min/avg/max/mdev')
                            ping=pingresult[ping+19:-6]
                            print(ping)
                            cursor.execute('update classement set Ping = "%s" where Domain = "%s";' % (ping,Domain))
                            mariadb_connection.commit()
mariadb_connection.close()
```

Comment: You are iterating ``cursor``, so you should not use it for anything else in your loop. Either fetch your data into a variable, or create a new cursor object for the update.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it's work perfectly now with a second cursor.